# Error de main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy iniciando en esto de pygame y me sale en este error de main()

> missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
import pygame
import random
r1=pygame.Rect(0,0,0,0)
pygame.init()

class Recs(object):
    def __init__(self,numeroinicia):
        self.lista=[]

        for x in range(numeroinicia):
            #creo un rect random
            leftrandom=random.randrange(2,560)
            toprandom=random.randrange(-580,-10)
            width=random.randrange(10,30)
            height=random.randrange(15,30)
            self.lista.append(pygame.Rect(leftrandom,toprandom,width,height))


    def reagrear(self):
        for x in range(len(self.lista)):
            if self.lista[x].top>482:
                leftrandom=random.randrange(2,560)
                toprandom=random.randrange(-580,-10)
                width=random.randrange(10,30)
                height=random.randrange(15,30)
                self.lista[x]=(pygame.Rect(leftrandom,toprandom,width,height))


    def agregarotro(self):
        pass
    def mover(self):
        for rectangulo in self.lista:
            rectangulo.move_ip(0,2)

    def pintar(self,superficie):
        for rectangulo in self.lista:
            pygame.draw.rect(superficie,(200,0,0),rectangulo)
            #color de los cuadros

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,imagen):
        self.imagen=imagen

        self.rect=self.imagen.get_rect()
        self.rect.top,self.rect.left=(100,200)
    def mover(self,vx,vy):
        self.rect.move_ip(vx,vy)
        if self.rect.left<0:
            vx=-vx
        self.rect.move_ip(vx,vy)

    def update(self,superficie):
        superficie.blit(self.imagen,self.rect)

def colision(player,recs):
    for rec in recs.lista:
        if player.rect.colliderect(rec):
            return True
            return False


def main(self):

    import pygame

    pygame.init()

    pantalla=pygame.display.set_mode((600,480))
    salir=False
    reloj1= pygame.time.Clock()
    imagen1=pygame.image.load("imagen2.png").convert_alpha()
    imagenexplosion=pygame.image.load("explosion.png").convert_alpha()
    imagenfondo=pygame.image.load("fondo.png").convert_alpha()
    #pygame.mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
    sonido1=pygame.mixer.Sound("sonido.wav")
    recs1=Recs(25)
    player1=Player(imagen1)

    #variables aux
    player1=Player(imagen1)
    vx,vy=0,0
    velocidad=10
    leftsigueapretada,rightsigueapretada,upsigueapretada,downsigueapretada=False,False,False,False
    colisiono=False

    #pygame.mixer.music.play(2

    while salir!=True:#LOOP PRINCIPAL
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                salir=True



        reloj1.tick(20)


        if colision(player1,recs1):
            colisiono=True
            player1.imagen=imagenexplosion
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            #pongo la explocion
        if colisiono==False:    
            recs1.mover()
            player1.mover(vx, vy)


        def __init__(self, lista):
            self.lista =lista
            def darlista(self):
                return self.lista

            def mover(self):
                for Recs in self.lista:
                    Recs.move_ip(50,50)
                #tamaño de los cuadros

            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                 for recs in self.lista:
                     if r1.colliderect(recs):
                         sonido1.play()
                         recs.width=0
                         recs.height=0


    (r1.left,r1.top)=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    #posision del roton en el cuadro
    r1.left-=r1.width/2
    r1.top-=r1.height/2
    pantalla.fill((0,0,0))
    pantalla.blit(imagenfondo,(0,0))

    for recs in self.lista:
        pantalla.blit(imagen1,(300,300))
        pygame.draw.rect(pantalla,(0,200,0),recs)
        pygame.draw.rect(pantalla,(10,10,10),r1)
        pantalla.blit(info,(5,5))
    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Comment: esto es Android???

Comment: En la función main le estas pasando un parametro, self, que luego cuando la invocas no le pasas. No se si funcionará pero prueba con un this. (o quitando el self)

Comment: asi ?class self:
        def __init__(self, lista):
                self.lista =lista
                def darlista(self):
                    return self.lista

Comment: Como dice Diego, tu función `main` queda definida como `def main(self)`. Lo cual indica que requiere un parámetro de entrada (`self`) que no proporcionas al llamarla. No obstante, no termino de entender tu idea, el parámetro self se usa por convención para permitir a una instancia autoreferenciarse y es pasado como primer parámetro a los métodos de instacia. Tu `main` no está dentro de una clase por lo que no es un método, además dentro defines un método `__init__` que es un inicializador/ constructor de clase pero no hay clase que inicializar.

Comment: Quita el `def main(self):` y sustituyelo por `main()`